# Alter property name on a Vertex Class didnt modify the property name in already existing records.

Tags: orientdb

I am using orientdb 2.1.3. Newly added records take the modified name. But the existing records are still having the old name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "update Class remove oldProperty" to delete the oldProperty.